# Character counter for form_for form not updating the count in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I implemented a form text_field character counter that works within the jsfiddle but not within the app.  It appears but won't count in real time as it does in the jsfiddle.  When i reload the page it will count the current characters in the text_field.

I do have more javascript within the page but i tried testing it by deleting all the other java instead of the coutner and it still won't work.

What is also odd is that I have a

`minlength: 20, maxlength: 1000`

Which when not validated, a toggle will appear with the count and will count in real time until the minlength is accomplished.  My goal is to translate that counter to under the text_field so it's always showing/counting the characters

**Here's my code:**

```
<%= form.label :description %>
<%= form.text_area :description, class: "form-control message", :rows => 10, minlength: 20, maxlength: 1000, required: true    %>
<span class="countdown"></span>
```

**Jquery:**

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    updateCountdownAll();
    $('.message').live('input', updateCountdown);

    });

    function updateCountdownAll() {
        $('.message').each(function () {
            updateCountdown(this);
        });
    }

    function updateCountdown(e) {

        var currentElement;
        if (e.target) {
            currentElement = e.target;
        } else {
            currentElement = e;
        }

        var maxLengh = $(currentElement).attr('maxlength');
        var remaining = $(currentElement).val().length;
        $(currentElement).nextAll('.countdown:first').text(remaining + '/' + maxLengh);
    }
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4bozw3k5/

Is there anything I can do to the code so it works within the rails app? in real time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, any error messages in browser inspection tool? Have you installed the gem `jquery-rails` if not, visit the link below and install it.

https://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-rails/versions/4.3.1

Secondly, it could be because .`live()` has been depreciated and as per version 1.9 completely removed.

Try using the event handler `.on()` instead.

Thirdly, it's an awful lot of code, bordering on a bit of spaghetti-code for something really simple. What I would do to simplify it:

```
    $(".message").on("keyup", function () {
        var maxlength = $(this).attr("maxlength")
        var remaining = $(this).val().length
        $(this).next().text(remaining + '/' + maxLengh)
    })
```

No need to wrap it in a $(document).ready(), too many $(document).ready() is going to slow down loading time (by increasing scripting time) when refreshing your app. Depending on how you've setup your rails app to execute javascript you can wrap all your javascript/jquery in one big $(document).ready() instead that will execute ***once*** when refreshing the app.

Besides, .on() is an event-listener that is listening and waiting for something to happen, for instance, .on("keyup", function(). You can switch the event listener off by using `$(".message").off()`

A bit of over-sharing, but knowing how event listeners and event delegation is vital for writing good jQuery.

Comment: Wow you're right.  Using `.on` instead of `.live` solved it.  But as for simplifying the code, with the example, how would i view the countdown then? Sorry if it's something obvious but im obviously not too trained in javascript or jquery

Comment: I made a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/2185mr9x/  – Don't forget to mark this answer as correct if it helped you!